# How can I best explain in a interview that my contract was terminated?

Tags: united-states, termination, contractors

My goal is to get another job as soon as possible.

Some months ago I was hired by an US company as a remote worker (I am not an US person, I am not an US resident). I signed a consulting agreement.

I worked for them 4 months. Then I went through a performance review and they told me I was doing good.

Two months after that review, without receiving any warning (not even during our 1 to 1 meetings with my boss or via a Slack message), the boss of my boss scheduled a meeting with me. I joined, a HR person was there, the boss of my boss told me they had decided to terminate my contract due to my performance.

After that, I received an email from HR telling me that was a letter to acknowledge my separation from their company.

Then I received and signed a letter agreement concerning the cessation of my independent contractor relationship

Comment: What's wrong with the truth?

Comment: @nidano2184 Don't tell them that it was due to performance. Tell them that you worked for the company for 6 months and then the contract ended. You don't need to tell them that you were terminated or that it was due to performance.

Answer (score 11):

#### Just tell them the truth.

"I worked as a contractor for company xyz for 6 months.  The contract ended at the customer's choice."

If pushed on why the contract was cancelled, "Well, they said it was for performance, but my only performance review was good, and the contract was ended suddenly without much feedback.  It was always a contracting agreement that could be cancelled without notice, so I just assumed they had reasons they didn't want to tell me."

That said, if they fired you for good reasons (like they told you that your output was sub-standard) you should come up with a reason for it that fits the data.  You should assume that your next employer will be best friends with your previous one.

Comment: Agreed although I might keep out the part about it being due to performance should they push.

Comment: "Contract was not renewed." It happens.